# Как из модального окна сделать ссылку

Tags: html

Имеется модальное окно `<a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> Войти</a>`,
при нажатии на данное модальное окно не меняется сама ссылка.
Как можно сделать ссылку чтоб при переходе открывалась страница с данным модальным окном.

```
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        ?>   
            <div class="loginpanel_block" style="padding-top:5px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; display:inline-block;padding-bottom: 2px;">

                <div class=" loginpanel_block lk_text" style="display:inline-block;">
                    Личный кабинет
                </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block" class=" loginpanel_block">

                    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reg"> Регистрация</a>
                    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"> Войти</a>
                </div>
            </div>


        <?php
    }

    else {
        ?>
```

Comment: Код будет? У URL засунуть флаг состояния модального окна.

Comment: Изменила текст.

Comment: @SaNsA_St4Rk Это не модальное окно, а просто ссылка(даже просто HTML тег)

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста перефразируйте Ваш вопрос, потому что честно говоря я запутался в попытках понять какую цель нужно достичь?!

P.S.: И можно побольше кода показать?

Comment: Хочу сделать ссылку с другого сайта чтоб при нажатии открывался этот сайт с уже выведенным модальным окном.

Comment: @SaNsA_St4Rk в таком случае вам нужна прямая ссылка на сайт с уже выведенным модальным окном (попробуйте покопаться в сетевых запросах в момент вызова модального окна на том сайте, вдруг повезёт). Если такой ссылки не существует, то — не судьба. Если на другом конце вызова находится ваш сайт, то вам следует подготовить такую ссылку.